# Automatically delete old files from a specified folder?

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I want to set up an automatic task that will automatically delete files older than X days from a specific folder. I'd prefer to do it without having to install any 3rd party software, but I'll be ok if it's a very small and simple utility.

I want this to force me to keep my files organized. I am setting my browser to download to a standard folder, and then with this script to automatically delete files older than a week, I will be forced to move & organize downloaded files I want to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Belvedere](http://lifehacker.com/5510961/how-to-automatically-clean-and-organize-your-desktop-downloads-and-other-folders) from one of [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/)'s editors.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy with Windows Scripting Host. A sample script looks something like this:

```
numDays = 7

Set objfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFso.GetFile("C:\test.txt")

Sub DeleteOldFile(objFile, numDays)
    dateFile = objFile.DateLastModified
    dateToday = Now()

    If dateFile <= dateToday Then
        daysOld = dateToday - dateFile
        If daysOld > numDays Then
            objFile.Delete
        End If
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Incorrect date stamp in", strFile
    End If

End Sub
```

You would need to write your script then run it as a scheduled task. Maybe thirty minutes after you log on on Friday mornings to give yourself one last chance to get those files you want to keep moved.
The complete [source](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Age-Based-File-Deletion-in-WSH/) for this example.

Answer (score 1):

I coded myself a solution for this a while back right before I found [**DelOld**](http://winhlp.com/node/386). It's a **very** small tool which does exactly what you want, and it is available as a .jar file, wrapped java executable, Visual Basic executable (MSVBVM60.DLL required), and of course as source code.

Simply supply it 2 command-line arguments -- the path of the folder, and the number of days before a file should be deleted. It can also be run through a batch script via Task Scheduler.

example:

```
DelOld.exe "C:\Downloads" 30
```

This will delete all files older than 30 days under `C:\Downloads`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a windows command called forfiles. I think it was on the windows 2000 resource kit.
I found a link to it from petri's web site: http://www.petri.co.il/download_free_reskit_tools.htm
It has a lot you can do with it including removing individual files based on how old they are or whole directories.